Как расставить знаки препинания с "такие, как" и "в том числе" в данном предложении?
Такие современные писатели (?) как Иванов и Петров (?) хорошо известны молодёжи (?) в том числе в Чехии.

Правильно:
Такие современные писатели, как Иванов и Петров, хорошо известны молодёжи, в том числе в Чехии.
Пояснение
Розенталь § 42. Сравнительный оборот, пункт 3
 3. Сравнительный оборот с союзом как выделяется запятыми в 
 следующих случаях:
 2) если в основной части предложения имеется указательное 
 слово (так, такой, тот, столь):  …Я всё сделаю, чтобы стать 
 такой, как она (Пан.); Ямщик был в таком же изумлении от 
 его щедрости, как и сам француз от предложения Дубровского 
 (П.); Черты лица его были те же, как и у сестры (Л. Т.); 

ПАС § 78
Обороты со значением включения, исключения и замещения обособляются по условиям контекста. В большинстве случаев такие обороты обособляются, так как обозначают дополнительную или уточняющую информацию.
